# Bootstapping hazard rates with non-linear interpolators

Tags: bootstrapping, quantlib

I have been using QuantLib 1.6.2 to bootstrap the hazard rates from a CDS
curve. My code is similar to the example "`CDS.cpp`" that comes with the
QuantLib distribution, i.e.,

```
boost::shared_ptr<PiecewiseDefaultCurve<HazardRate, BackwardFlat> >
hazardRateStructure(new PiecewiseDefaultCurve<HazardRate, BackwardFlat>
(todaysDate, instruments, Actual365Fixed()));
```

I tried to experiment with different non-linear interpolation methods (instead of `BackwardFlat` listed above) such as:

```
    CubicNaturalSpline
    KrugerCubic
    Parabolic
    FritschButlandCubic
    MonotonicParabolic
```

but I am getting the error "`no appropriate default constructor available`". What is the proper way of passing one of  these interpolators to the
`PiecewiseDefaultCurve` class?

Thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

[Note: in case someone stumbles on this question, I'm copying here the answer I gave you on the QuantLib mailing list.]

The classes you're listing are the actual interpolation classes, but the curve is expecting a corresponding factory class (for instance, `BackwardFlat` in the example is the factory for the `BackwardFlatInterpolation` class).  In the case of cubic interpolations, you'll have to use the `Cubic` class. By default, it builds Kruger interpolations (I'm not aware of the reason for the choice) so if you write:

```
PiecewiseDefaultCurve<HazardRate, Cubic>(todaysDate, instruments, Actual365Fixed())
```

you'll get a curve using the `KrugerCubic` class.  To get the other interpolations, you can pass a `Cubic` instance with the corresponding parameters (you can look them up in the constructors of the interpolation classes); for instance,

```
PiecewiseDefaultCurve<HazardRate, Cubic>(todaysDate, instruments, Actual365Fixed(),
                                         1e-12, Cubic(CubicInterpolation::Spline, false))
```

will give you a curve using the `CubicNaturalSpline` class, and

```
PiecewiseDefaultCurve<HazardRate, Cubic>(todaysDate, instruments, Actual365Fixed(),
                                         1e-12, Cubic(CubicInterpolation::Parabolic, true))
```

will use the `MonotonicParabolic` class.